# Unable to understand a line in .vimrc

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I do not understand what the following line does in .vimrc

```
nmap <silent> <leader>v :EditConfig<cr>
```

It seems that

- nmap mean noremap
- silent seems to mean apparently no beep in Vim
- leader seems to mean the first character in the mode :
- v seems to mean visual mode
- EditConfig should be a command in vim in the mode : *(However, it is not.)*

**What does the line mean in .vimrc?**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

- `nmap` means "map a key sequence when in normal mode" (see vim's [docs](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/map.html)).
- `<silent>` tells vim to show no message when this key sequence is used.
- `<leader>` means the key sequence starts with the character assigned to variable `mapleader` -- a backslash, if no `let mapleader =` statement has executed yet at the point `nmap` executes.

And the `v` is the rest of the key sequence.

So overall this is mapping, in normal mode, a backslash-v key sequence to show no message and execute `:EditConfig` which is likely a function defined previously in the vimrc to edit configuration files (see for example [this](http://github.com/dm3/vim-config/blob/69cdf3a4fab5481ac160994dec7a0ef0ef6307e8/_vimrc) vimrc, search in browser for editconfig). `:call EditConfig()` at the end (as the vimrc file I gave the URL to uses) would be better, I believe.

Comment: @Alex: Thank you for your answer! I have the pieces of information now in my notebook, not to make the same mistakes again :)

Comment: Why `:call EditConfig()` would be better than `:EditConfig`?  :curious-n00b-face:

Answer (score 5):

It would appear that you are missing a function...

Try,

```
function! EditConfig()
    for config in ['$MYGVIMRC', '$MYVIMRC']
        if exists(config)
            execute 'edit '.config
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

[Check this example](http://jeremycantrell.com/files/vimrc.html).