# How to get line numbers of selected text in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to get the line numbers of selected text to pass to an external command?

Context: I'd like to integrate `pyfmt` into vim. Ideally, I'd like to be able to select some text and type some shortcut to have the selected text reformatted by `pyfmt`.

So far I've found that running `!pyfmt -i %` will format the whole file. `pyfmt` also supports a `--lines START-END` option. I'd like to be able to pass the line numbers of the beginning and end of the selected text to `pyfmt` so that only what I want to reformat gets reformatted. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a selection you can use `line("'<")` to get the start of the last selection and `line("'>")` to get the end of it

Answer (score 2):

Select the lines you want to format (preferably linewise, using capital <kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual mode), and then, without leaving visual mode, type `:!pyfmt -i`.

This will not give you the line numbers.  Instead, it will filter the selected lines through the command and replace them with the output.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide my case as follow and I think it can be customized to your case, easily.

---

I have a **Vim-Plug** plugin `Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'`, and it has a command: (`l`,`r` are line numbers)

```
:l,rCommentary
```

When you `v`isual-selected lines in Vim and then press `:` you will get:

```
:'<,'>
```

Based on this observation the command I need is: (`v`isual mode mapping)

```
vnoremap <silent> my_shortcut :Commentary<CR>gv
```

i.e. I just need `:Commentary` since when it execute `:` the `'<,'>` is added for you.

---

To understand `<silent>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/962118/5290519